# How to delete an item from a nested array by id in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a data model called Calendar and contains an array of events:

```js
{
        "_id": "64ed0c1c706147ee90a1ca00",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": 7,
        "day": 25,
        "events": [
            {
                "title": "return back to the Netherlands",
                "description": "check ID and paper",
                "_id": "64ed0c1c706147ee90a1ca01"
            },
            {
                "title": "finish the exam",
                "description": "celebrating with Hua",
                "_id": "64ed0c1c706147ee90a1ca02"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2023-08-28T21:05:32.928Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-28T21:05:32.928Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

now I want to delete an event according to its _id and code is like:

```js
router.route('/:year/:month/:day/:eventId').delete(async (req, res) => {
    const year = Number(req.params.year);
    const month = Number(req.params.month);
    const day = Number(req.params.day);
    const eventId = req.params.eventId;

    try {
        const updatedCalendar = await Calendar.findOneAndUpdate(
            { year, month, day },
            { $pull: { events: { _id: eventId } } },
            { new: true }
        );

      if (updatedCalendar) {
          return res.json(updatedCalendar);
      } else {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Date entry not found.' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
          return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error removing event.', error: error.message });
      }
});
```

I tried in insomnia by choosing delete and url:
http://localhost:3000/Calendar/2023/7/25/64ed0c1c706147ee90a1ca01 , it return 404 not found: cannot delelte Calendar/2023/7/25/64ed0c1c706147ee90a1ca01.

What's the problem and how I could make it work?

I also tried post, it doesn't work, either.